# select mysql data not belonging to the row but belong to the same order id

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to get a list some data that belogs to the same order_id.

```
----- ----------- ------- -------- -------  --------- ------
 ID. | order_id | f_name | l_name | phone | relation | dob |
----- ----------- ------- -------- ------- ----------- -----
1.      123.      mom.     smith.   123123. primary.    null
2       123       dad      smith.           spouse      null
3.      123.      son.     smith.           son.       06282013
```

The data is set in this way where the order_id is the same but as yo u can see only the child has a dob.  What I am trying to run is a mysql query where I can bring all children from age 6-12 along with the phone number from the primary

Real Sql query.  This brings the children but not the primary with the telephone number that i Need.

```
select ea.* from event_attendee ea
JOIN event_order eo on ea.order_id = eo.id
JOIN event e on eo.event_id = e.id
where e.id = '0d323c3a-33f3-4583-8b10-65100403edc2' and date_of_birth >= '2007-01-01 00:00:00' and date_of_birth <= '2020-01-2014 00:00:00' group by event_order_id;
```

any ideas?

Comment: What does your query have to do with the sample data you have shown?

Comment: Could you provide a SQL fiddle with all the schemas? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, this is a join:

```
select c.*, p.phone
from data p join
     data c
     on p.order_id = c.order_id and
        p.relation = 'parent' and
        c.relation = 'child'
where c.dob > curdate() - interval 13 year and
      c.dob <= curdate() - interval 6 year;
```

Note:  This assumes that `dob` is stored properly as a date.